# What is 'more correct' way to finish the letter?

Tags: letter-writing

Is it

> Hope to hear from you soon.

or

> I look forward to hearing from you soon.

or neither?

Comment: (It) just depends on how formal you want to (wanna) be. Your first sentence is something I would use for good friends or family members, the other one for more distant folks or more professional contexts.

Comment: @Clare Hi Claire, could you please copy it over as an answer so I could accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It) just depends on how formal you want to (wanna) be. Your first sentence is something I would use for good friends or family members, the other one for more distant folks or more professional contexts.